# API calls not happening on opening of Cefsharp application in Testcomplete

Tags: cefsharp, testcomplete

I have a Cefsharp application which has Html pages with Javascript. Js makes API calls which happens fine if I open cef application in windows but most of API calls are not happening when I am opening same cef application through testcompelete.

On debugging application I am getting CORS warning.
I am using CefCustomScheme which has root folder path, schemeName and host name specified. And provided same shemeName and host name in Address in *wpf: chromiumwebrowse* tag. If I hard-code root folder path in Address Source binding, its working fine even in testcomplete.

```
private static CefCustomScheme GetAlmanacScheme(IAppSettings appSettings)
        {
            try
            {
                var almanacFolder = appSettings.Settings["ALMANAC_WIDGET_PATH"];
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(almanacFolder))
                {
                    almanacFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "Thermo", "InstConnectAgent", "AlmanacWidget");
                }
                var factory = new FolderSchemeHandlerFactory(almanacFolder, "thermo", "almanac");
                return new CefCustomScheme() { SchemeName = "thermo", SchemeHandlerFactory = factory, IsCorsEnabled = true };
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and Source is

```
private const string WidgetUrl = "thermo://almanac";
public string Source
        {
            get
            {
                return WidgetUrl;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by API call?

Comment: Web API (HTTP services- get, post, put) calls

Comment: Did you check the log file? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: I used chromium dev-tools to debug on specified port, through that I got to know about CORS warning.

Comment: Thanks for providing link.